# How to cut a for-comprehension short (break out of it) in scala?

Tags: scala, break, for-comprehension, infinite-sequence

I have a piece of code which would code as follows:

```
val e2 = for (e <- elements if condition(expensiveFunction(e))) yield {
            expensiveFunction(e)
         }
```

Where the condition will be true for a few elements and then become false for all remaining ones.

Unfortunately this doesn't work (even if I ignore performance) because my `elements` is an infinite iterator.

Is there a way to use a "break" in a for-comprehension so it stops yielding elements when a certain condition holds? Otherwise, what would be the scala-idiomatic way to compute my `e2`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I break out of a loop in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala)

Comment: That question is about a regular loop, not a for-comprehension (i.e., with yield). I suspect takeWhile can be part of the solution...

Comment: The question is somehow different, but answers (as far as I understand) can be applied to your situation as well

Comment: for-comprehensions are completely different than traditional loops under the covers. The fact that they share similar syntax is to make them easier to read.

Comment: The duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343531/how-to-yield-a-single-element-from-for-loop-in-scala

Comment: That's not a duplicate either, as it asks for only one item, not a few like this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I break out of a loop in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742719/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-loop-in-scala)

Comment: Yes, the solution is the same, but that question is ill-phrased: a "for (<-)" is a comprehension, not a loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
scala> def compute(i: Int) = { println(s"f$i"); 10*i }
compute: (i: Int)Int

scala> for (x <- Stream range (0, 20)) yield compute(x)
f0
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> res0 takeWhile (_ < 100)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> res1.toList
f1
f2
f3
f4
f5
f6
f7
f8
f9
f10
res2: List[Int] = List(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
```

Edit, another demonstration:

```
scala> def compute(i: Int) = { println(s"f$i"); 10*i }
compute: (i: Int)Int

scala> for (x <- Stream range (0, 20)) yield compute(x)
f0
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> res0 takeWhile (_ < 100)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> res1.toList
f1
f2
f3
f4
f5
f6
f7
f8
f9
f10
res2: List[Int] = List(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)

scala> Stream.range(0,20).map(compute).toList
f0
f1
f2
f3
f4
f5
f6
f7
f8
f9
f10
f11
f12
f13
f14
f15
f16
f17
f18
f19
res3: List[Int] = List(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190)

scala> Stream.range(0,20).map(compute).takeWhile(_ < 100).toList
f0
f1
f2
f3
f4
f5
f6
f7
f8
f9
f10
res4: List[Int] = List(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
```

Comment: In my terminology, that is `(for(e <- elements) yield expensiveFunction(e)).takeWhile(r => condition(r))`. I am surprised at how obvious it is. Looks like reasoning about infinite iterators is still difficult for me.

Comment: @jsalvata note (for(...)...) takeWhile condition. Placeholder syntax, leaving off the placeholder because of expected type. And losing the dot and parens. Others have got me hooked on minimalism.

Comment: This seems to compute the `expensiveFunction` for *all* elements - and truncate the resulting sequence only *after* the computation.

Comment: @javadba What do you observe that suggests that? Compare `Stream.range(0,20).map(compute).toList` and `Stream.range(0,20).map(compute).takeWhile(_ < 100).toList`. The collection is not realized after each operation from left to right.

Comment: @javadba it depends on the collection used.  For strict collections it will compute all elements, for lazy ones it will not.

Comment: I tested this on a non-lazy collection - by adding print statements before each return value: the `expensiveFucnction` gets invoked on all elements and then the result is truncated. That is *not* the case for the `toIterator` approach from @om-nom-nom: that one correctly invokes expensiveFunction` only the min required times.

Comment: @javadba Stream is lazy, is the point. I hope that clears it up. As you can see, your previous assertion about my example is not correct.

Comment: @javadba sorry, I just looked at the question again, the point was how to take a prefix, so actually strict was beside the point. In the comments, there are a couple of near-duplicates that didn't satisfy the OP.

Comment: OK it's more clear now : the answer shown here is intended for lazy collections.  It's not clear to me what the OP intended: but in any case useful to have the distinction of answers supporting both approaches to collections . I will leave my comment above since i can not edit it - and deleting it would lose the context of the thread.

Answer (score 20):

You could go with lazy approach:

```
val e2 = elements.toIterator                    
          .map(expensiveFunction)
          .takeWhile(result => result == true) // or just .takeWhile(identity)
// you may want to strict iterator, (e.g. by calling .toList) at the end
```

So you compute expensiveFunction on demand, and if there is false on some step, you won't do unnecessary work.

Comment: +1 -- still, because my particular case is more clearly written as a for-comprehension, I'm accepting som-snytt's answer. Thanks.

Comment: This may actually be the *best* answer:  the one from @som-snytt invokes the `expensiveFunction` for all elements - and only *afterwards* discards the unwanted results.

Comment: @javadba No, for comprehension desugars to map. I think my answer was to the question about `for`? Otherwise they are the same.

Comment: I used *may* in a polite manner but actually I had *tested* this and *verified* that your approach is not greedy whereas that from @som-snytt does incur full cost of the *expensiveFunction* even on unused/unneeded elements.

Comment: The recent comments about lazy/strict are interesting because `elements` is already an iterator, per the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use takeWhile:

```
elements.takeWhile(condition(expensiveFunction(_)))
```

Comment: I could use `elements.takeWhile(e => condition(expensiveFunction(e))`, but then I would need to re-compute the expensiveFunction for each of them again.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution:

```
(for (e <- elements) yield {
  val x= expensiveFunction(e)
  if (condition(x)) Some(x) else None
}).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).map(_.get)
```

A better one, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea:
If the elements is a lazy container already(like Stream, Iterator):

```
(for (e <- elements; 
      buf = expensiveFunction(e);  
      if condition(buf)) yield buf).headOption
```

Or not:

```
(for (e <- elements.view; 
      buf = expensiveFunction(e);  
      if condition(buf)) yield buf).headOption
```