# scala : type mismatch(found unit, you need int)

Tags: scala

Just started with Scala. Everytime I try to execute it, a mismatch error is shown. I'm returning integer only. Still the compiler finds type `Unit` from god knows where.

```
object a {
  def search(e : Int,arr : Array[Int]): Int = {
    var l: Int = 0
    for(l <- 0 arr.length) {
      if(arr(l) == e) {
        return e
      } else {
        return -1
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {  
    var i = 0
    println("enter the number of elements ")
    var n = readLine.toInt

    println("enter the elements are")
    var arr = new Array[Int](n)
    for(i <- 0 to n-1) {
      println("enter element "+i+" ")
      arr(i) = readLine.toInt
    }
    for(i <- 0 to n-1) {
      println("element "+i+" is "+arr(i))
    }

    println("sorted array is")
    arr = arr.sortWith(_ < _)
    for(i <- 0 to n-1) {
      println(arr(i))
    }

    println("enter the number to be searched ")
    var e = readLine.toInt
    var result: Int = search(e,arr)
    if(result == e) {
      println("element found")
    } else {
      println("element not found")
    }
  }
}
```

output

```
yudhveer@lfc:~$ scalac a.scala
a.scala:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
        for(l<-0 until arr.length)
                 ^
one error found
```

Comment: A more ideomatic way to write this in Scala could be http://pastebin.com/UrTSsDt1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More scalish approaches to `search` as originally defined above, which benefits from functional immutability and Scala idiomatic elements. Note array inclusion conveys the intended semantics,

```
def search(e : Int, arr : Array[Int]): Int = if (arr contains e) e else -1
```

Using a for comprehension we yield found elements and test for non emptiness in the resulting list,

```
def search(e : Int, arr : Array[Int]): Int = {
  val res = for (a <- arr if a == e) yield a
  if (res.nonEmpty) res.head else -1
}
```

Relevant here is that we iterate over each element of `arr` without having to use indexing. Also consider `exists` which will halt on first match encountered,

```
def search(e : Int, arr : Array[Int]): Int = if (arr.exists( _ ==  e)) e else -1
```

Using `find` we deliver the found value or else `-1`,

```
def search(e : Int, arr : Array[Int]): Int = arr.find(_ == e).getOrElse(-1)
```

Note that `find` returns an `Option`, either `Some(value)` or `None` if none were found; with `getOrElse` we handle the not found case.

Answer (score 2):

The basic cause of the error is in the `for`, you forget the `yield`.

On a larger scale you run in a classical transition problem from Java to Scala.
You can not break a for loop. (In reality you can but only in a hacky way: [How to yield a single element from for loop in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343531/how-to-yield-a-single-element-from-for-loop-in-scala/13344088#13344088)).

A possible approach here is to make use of the great Scala Collection Library whcih allready contains the function you implemented: `indexOf` :

```
def search(e : Int,arr : Array[Int]) : Int = arr.indexOf(e)
```

Will give the expected result.